# Why is the Firebase SDK for unity bigger then what it says in the Firebase website?

Tags: firebase, unity-game-engine, sdk

I was creating a new project with Firebase and when i clicked to download the SDK there was written that it is approximately 300 MB but the download size was 2.2 GB.
I only need one package so is there a way to download the packages separately?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll answer this in multiple parts:

1. Bugs, including bugs in the Firebase Dashboard, can be filed [here](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report).
2. The best way to download the packages individually is through the Unity Package Manager ([follow these steps](https://firebase.google.com/docs/unity/setup#add-sdks-upm)).
3. Why is it so big (and corollary, why isn't it as big in the Unity Package Manager, source control, &c):

The size of the SDK comes down to two factors:

1. each unitypackage includes all of the packages it depends on. Therefore, common logic like `FirebaseCore` or even `FirebaseAnalytics` gets repeatedly included. This greatly simplifies integration logic (Unity is smart enough to not import code you've already imported, but not smart enough to conditionally pull in other unitypackage files if you forget) but explodes the size of the SDK (it's essentially a zip file of zip files, each of which includes redundant data).
2. The Unity SDK is actually built on top of the [open source C++ SDK](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-cpp-sdk). Since there's not a good way to integrate a C++ build into Unity's build system, this means that there are redundant copies of every SDK for iOS, Android, MacOS, Windows, and Linux included for every library and every supported architecture. The Firebase SDK itself supports Unity versions back to the 5 series which also means C++ platforms and toolchains that Unity itself has abandoned support for but which will still get updates from Firebase.

So why is the Unity Package Manager integration smaller?

UPM is [built on top of NPM](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CustomPackages.html), which means that only the exact Firebase libraries you need get downloaded. That means that you don't download .NET 3.x compatible libraries or 10 copies of Firebase Core. The packages also live in a separate `Library` directory in Unity (which you shouldn't keep in version control - saving space there) and can be downloaded on demand as you need them (technically they also live in a [package cache](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-cache.html) in your user directory).

I hope that helps! And any comments/suggestions on how you'd like to see it further improved can be filed as [a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/report/features) or as an issue on the [Unity Quickstart](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-unity).

Comment: Thanks this was helpful. They shouldn't keep an old information there because that could mislead people.